# Taking user input

Tags: android, user-input

I'm trying to create a guess the word type of game. I have created an edit text field for the user to enter the word. How do I get the data once the user has pressed the return key on the virtual keyboard. Previously I had tried to get the data by creating a button and once the user clicks the button, the data is retrieved. But this seems to be roundabout way of resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
    public class AndroidEnterKeyActivity extends Activity implements 
    OnKeyListener {

     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     editText1.setOnKeyListener(this);
     EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      editText2.setOnKeyListener(this);

      }

  @Override
   public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

   TextView responseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseText);
   EditText myEditText = (EditText) view;

  if (keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
  keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
  event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
  event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

   if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {
   Log.v("AndroidEnterKeyActivity","Enter Key Pressed!");
   switch (view.getId()) {
   case R.id.editText1:
    responseText
  .setText("Just pressed the ENTER key, " +
  "focus was on Text Box1. " +
  "You typed:\n" + myEditText.getText());
 break;
 case R.id.editText2:
 responseText
 .setText("Just pressed the ENTER key, " +
  "focus was on Text Box2. " +
  "You typed:\n" + myEditText.getText());
 break;
   }
   return true; 
 }                

 }
  return false; // pass on to other listeners. 

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setOnEditorActionListener()` for last edit text

Code for layout xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/signinscr_userName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/userName"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/signinscr_password"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Code for `.java` file

```
EditText userNameField = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.signinscr_userName);
EditText passwordField = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.signinscr_password);
passwordField.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent 
arg2) {
        //Do your operation here.
        return false;
    }
});
```